# how change default display of WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have deployed a WCF service. When that service is accessed from web browsers it is showing a message :

> You have created a service.
>
> To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to
>   call the service. You can do this using the `svcutil.exe` tool from the
>   command line with the following syntax:
>
> svcutil.exe http://sitename/Service1.svc?wsdl
>
> You can also access the service description as a single file:
>
> http://sitename/Service1.svc?singleWsdl
>
> This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains
>   the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use
>   the generated client class to call the Service.

**How to change this default message shown by WCF service ?**

Comment: If i remember correctly it is not easy to do. I tried before and it was just too much hassle. Let me see if i can find the tutorial i found before.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override the `default` page. But you can use a [`Help Page`](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WCF-Custom-Help-Page-6f5a90f0). Also you could create a totally separate page to describe your service.